# Accessing UI thread of a form?

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

I'm using C# and I'm making an application where a lot of UI loading must be done in background. Is it possible to do it unsafely and ignore **InvalidOperationExceptions**? The only way I found it to put **try...catch** statements around every single line of code but this will take ages as there is too much code.

Comment: I can't use a helper function with an Invoke either

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you're trying to do?  Anything that touches the UI has to be done on the UI thread, which means Invoke or BeginInvoke: could you say what you're doing that rules out the "helper function with an Invoke"?

Comment: Your question is basically, ".NET is stopping me from doing a terrible abomination. How can I get around this?"

Comment: if it is coded well , nothing terrible will happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating UI directly from threads is a bad thing. If you have multiple threads trying to update, then you are in trouble,
If you are sure that only that thread is going to update the UI,

use this before invoking the thread

```
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls =False
```

Comment: @Srin at least you warned him... :)